# How to assign value to a property under an initialized parent property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

Say I have an object as below,

```
var ob = {}
```

Now I want to assign value to it as following

```
ob = {
  data: {
    id: '123456'
  }
}
```

I tried `ob.data.id = '123456'`, it prompts me that

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

Unless I make it this way

```
ob.data = {}
ob.data.id = '123456'
```

I'm wondering if there a easier/elegant way to achieve the same goal here? Much appreciated.

Comment: Try this instead `ob.data = {id: '123456'}`

Comment: If you're open to use lodash, then [`_.set`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set) will do your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ob = {};
ob.data.id = '123456';
```

The above code gives an error because, you have initialized the variable `ob` as an object but in the next line, you are trying to add a property `id` to `ob.data`. Here `ob.data` is not yet defined (`undefined`).

```
var ob = {};
ob.data = {};
ob.data.id = '123456';
```

This code works because, first you have initialized the variable `ob` as an object and then you have added a property `data` to it which is also an object and then finally adding the `id` property to the `ob.data` object.

As pointed out in the comment by @Lewis, you can combine the last two statements to a single statement as shown below.

```
var ob = {};
ob.data = {id: '123456'};
```

This would give the same result.